# Calculating input fields with data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, web

I have input fields with data attribute.I want when click on button in the field total to be the sum of total of all fields. I found the total sum for every field, but how to sum all of them.

```
<input type="text" id="total">
<div class="field">
  <input type="number" min="1" max="255" data-price="2" class="wert">
</div>
<div class="field">
  <input type="number" min="1" max="255" data-price="2" class="wert">
</div>
<button id="calc-butt">Sum</button>
<script>
 jQuery('#calc-butt').click(function() {
    jQuery('.field').each(function(){
      var price = jQuery(this).find('.wert').attr("data-price");
      var cubic = jQuery(this).find('.wert').val();
      var total = price * cubic;

    });
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scope of `total` is only inside the each callback, intialize it to 0 just before `each` ,check the snippet

```js
jQuery('#calc-butt').click(function() {
    var total = 0;
    jQuery('.field').each(function(){
      var price = jQuery(this).find('.wert').attr("data-price");
      var cubic = jQuery(this).find('.wert').val();
      total += price * cubic;
      jQuery('#total').val(total);
    });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="total">
<div class="field">
  <input type="number" min="1" max="255" data-price="2" class="wert">
</div>
<div class="field">
  <input type="number" min="1" max="255" data-price="2" class="wert">
</div>
<button id="calc-butt">Sum</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put the calculated values from each field into an array using `map` and reduce that array to get the total

```js
 jQuery('#calc-butt').on('click', function() {
    var values = jQuery('.field').map(function(){
      var price = jQuery(this).find('.wert').attr("data-price");
      var cubic = jQuery(this).find('.wert').val();
      return price * cubic;
    }).get();
    
    var total = values.reduce(function(a,b) { return a + b });
    
    $('#total').val(total);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="total">
<div class="field">
  <input type="number" min="1" max="255" data-price="2" class="wert">
</div>
<div class="field">
  <input type="number" min="1" max="255" data-price="2" class="wert">
</div>
<button id="calc-butt">Sum</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery('#calc-butt').click(function() {
    var sum = 0;
    var total = 0;
    jQuery('.wert').each(function(){
      var price = $(this).attr("data-price");
      var cubic = $(this).val();
      total += price * cubic;
      sum += Number(cubic);
    });
    
    alert('sum = ' + sum + ' total = ' + total);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="total">
<div class="field">
  <input type="number" min="1" max="255" data-price="2" class="wert">
</div>
<div class="field">
  <input type="number" min="1" max="255" data-price="2" class="wert">
</div>
<button id="calc-butt">Sum</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var totalInput = $('#total');
 
 $('#calc-butt').click(function() {
    var globalTotal = 0;
    $('.field').each(function(){
      var input = $(this).find('.wert');
      
      var price = input.attr("data-price");
      var cubic = input.val();
           
      var total = price * cubic;
      globalTotal += total;
    });
    totalInput.val(globalTotal);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="total">
<div class="field">
  <input type="number" min="1" max="255" data-price="2" class="wert">
</div>
<div class="field">
  <input type="number" min="1" max="255" data-price="3" class="wert">
</div>
<button id="calc-butt">Sum</button>
```

Try this, i hope it helps you.